# Mocha ESM Module: Stack trace only goes to .test.js file

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js

The error is originating in envFunctions.js. But the stack trace when running mocha is saying the error is coming from envFunctions.test.js. That's as far back as it goes.

```
SyntaxError[ @/Users/me/Dev/Projects/myproject/test/envFunctional.test.js ]: Unexpected identifier 'options'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:463:14)
```

I am running mocha v10.2.0, on a mac with M1 chip (if that matters), and running mocha via the terminal with this command:

```
mocha test --recursive --reporter spec --exit
```

Is there a way to improve this stack trace?

I ran it with node and yarn, and the stack trace is fine. So I was wondering if that has to do with mocha's support for es modules.

Specifically, the error is in the function declaration. If it's somewhere else then everything is stack traced properly. But if there is an error, for example, forgetting a comma when separating the params of the function, then the stack trace will fail.

Comment: I tried the mocha option --full-trace, but that also didn't work.